# Nginx doesn't say "starting ... reverse proxy" when I've tried to configure it as a reverse proxy, rather is says "starting ... web server"

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, centos

I'm setting up a new CentOS 7 Reverse Proxy with nginx.
When nginx starts it shows:

> Started nginx - high performance web server

I want a reverse proxy. Is there something to configure. I thought I would see:

> high performance web server and reverse proxy

Is there something I have done wrong or need to do here?

Comment: Is the reverse proxy working as intended despite the messaging?   I don't know much about either nginx or centos, but it seems likely to me that that message is from the system services scripts that don't know anything about how you actually configured nginx.

Comment: Check `/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service` file